# mongodb installation - error - chown: invalid group: ‘mongodb:mongodb’

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to install mongodb on ubuntu 14.10 following instructions from mongodb manual [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) . However I get the error `chown: invalid group: ‘mongodb:mongodb’` and not able to proceed further with this.

```
> sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell
  mongodb-org-tools
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 56 not upgraded.
..................................
..................................

Setting up mongodb-org-shell (3.4.2) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-server (3.4.2) ...
chown: invalid group: ‘mongodb:mongodb’
dpkg: error processing package mongodb-org-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up mongodb-org-mongos (3.4.2) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-tools (3.4.2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mongodb-org:
 mongodb-org depends on mongodb-org-server; however:
  Package mongodb-org-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mongodb-org (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-org-server
 mongodb-org
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
>
```

Comment: do you have user mongodb on your machine? check using id mongodb

Comment: It seems there is. When I use cat /etc/passwd I do not see the user `mongodb`, however when I try to add a new user it says already exists - `> sudo useradd mongodb
useradd: user 'mongodb' already exists
>
`

Answer (score 2):

Follow this commands, I hope, This will help you.

```bash
sudo userdel -r mongodb
sudo groupdel mongodb
sudo adduser mongodb
sudo groupadd mongodb
useradd -G mongodb mongodb
```

Comment: `> sudo userdel -r mongodb
userdel: cannot remove entry 'mongodb' from /etc/passwd`   and `> sudo groupdel mongodb
groupdel: group 'mongodb' does not exist`

Comment: sudo userdel -f mongodb  && sudo adduser mongodb      then retry installation